# When rendering in Eevee, result is zoomed in compared to viewport camera

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

I've been playing about with Blender 2.8, getting use to the interface etc. I've rendered a still frame from an animation, but the resulting image outputted is slightly zoomed in, this is the same wether I render in Eevee or Cycles. am I doing something wrong? or is this some weird bug?
[image: screen cap of eevee camera view]

screen cap of eevee camera view

[image: Actual Eevee render]

Actual Eevee render

[image: Cycles render]

Cycles render

[image: camera settings]

camera settings

If you need to see anything else please let me know

Best

simon